# How to harden CoreOS

Tags: coreos

One of our security expert has run vulnerability detection script on CoreOS and found few recommendations (Note this script is initially designed used with Linux OS)

Some of the VA issues reported by tools as below.

1. PASS_MAX_DAYS in /etc/login.defs must be set to 60
2. Field 5 of /etc/shadow must be 90

CoreOS doesn't allow me to edit /etc/login.defs as root user. The file is read-only for core and root users. I know this is in-vain as CoreOS uses ssh key based login. However I would like to know whether there is any other way to edit this files as I need to deal with few system files to fix more issues.

Do I need to use cloud-init tool to modify this file ? or is there any other alternative to harden CoreOS ?

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreos-user/87fluJrTuJE:

These types of files in /etc are actually symlinks pointing to files in /usr. This allows CoreOS to update them via auto-updates, but also give you the ability to break the symlinks and stick a customized file in its place. You can see this by listing out the directory:

```
$ ls -la /etc/ | grep login
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         32 Nov  8 19:00 login.access -> ../usr/share/shadow/login.access
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root         30 Nov  1 06:14 login.defs -> ../usr/share/shadow/login.defs
```

Obviously, edit these only if you know what you are doing. You should be able to do this cloud-config/ignition if you need to automate it.

Both of those recommendations have to do with login passwords. We do not recommend you use passwords at all and nearly all setups of CoreOS Linux use ssh keys instead.